# How to enable button on text change event in asp.net using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to enable button when some data is getting selected in textbox from search. I tried `OnTextChanged` but it throwing error.

> Too many characters in character literal

But, If I use `onKeyPress` then the button is getting enabled but only when I press any key inside the text.

Not sure, what event I should use to enable button if some data is getting selected in the textbox from autocomplete.

Textbox image attached.

[Textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frFDi.png)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="pName" runat="server" onTextChanged="EnableButton('SearchButton', 'ClearButton');"/>
```

Comment: Only enable or do you need to disable also when text is empty?

Comment: Do you need a jquery solution or the backend side?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your onTextChanged event no need if you are using the below code

You can add a class (txtName, btnClass) from your textbox and button like the below code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="pName" runat="server" CssClass="txtName" onTextChanged="EnableButton('SearchButton', 'ClearButton');"/>

<asp:ButtonID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btnClass"  Text="Submit" BorderStyle="Solid" ToolTip="Submit"/>
```

After that, you need to implement the jquery as per the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".txtName").keypress(function() {
        if ($(".txtName").val().trim().length > 0) {
            $(".btnClass").removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $(".btnClass").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

I hope it is working perfectly with your code.

Comment: No this is not working. I am still facing the same issue.  I used like `<asp:TextBox ID="pName" runat="server" CssClass="txtName" />` and the Jquery you provided. As I mentioned, I am not writing in textbox. The value is getting populated from autocomplete. I have attached the image as well.

Comment: It also complains that `keypress` is not a function.

Comment: If I do like this `<asp:TextBox ID="pName" runat="server" onKeyPress="EnableButton('SearchButton', 'ClearButton');"/>`. It enables button only when I press inside the texbox.